# Changing Custom Post Type Slug with Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks, slug

After reading countless answers on various websites including Stack Overflow and trying different solutions, I think I am losing the will to live because I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem that works - even though many people seem to have solved it one way or the other.

I have the following Custom Post Types on my WordPress website:

- **CPT**: `cpt_business`
- **Slug**: `cpt-slug`
- **Slug Rewrite**: `mycptbase`
- `with_front = false`

and I have the following Taxonomy:

- **Taxonomy**: `tax_business`
- **Slug**: `tax-slug`
- **Slug Rewrite**: `mytaxonomybase`
- `hierarchical = true`
- `with_front = false`

When I create a custom post titled `Business Name` in `cpt_business` Custom Post Type, the post has the following URL structure:

- `https://example.com/mycptbase/business-name/`

I want the post to have the following URL structure:

- `https://example.com/mytaxonomybase/mytaxonomy-1/mytaxonomy-2/business-name/`

In other words, I want my custom post type have the taxonomy's URL structure. The `tax_business` taxonomy is hierarchical, and can have up to 10 items - in which case, only the lowest item in the category tree is selected when creating the post.

I tried many, many different code samples. The closest to a solution I got was with the [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plug-in, however that insisted on keeping `mycptbase` in the permalinks - meaning my final URL ended up being `/mycptbase/mytaxonomy-1/mytaxonomy-2/business-name/`.

The second closest I got to a solution was the method described [here](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/taxonomy-slug-in-post-type-url.html), but with this one, it simply ignored the hierarchy in my taxonomy and only included the single taxonomy item selected.

I would genuinely appreciate if you can help me or point me in the right direction. Please note I am a total newbie when it comes to PHP and have a basic understanding of its role in WordPress.

It would be awesome if I can fix this problem by adding / amending a code in the `functions.php` file. I will give you a corona-free virtual hug if you can help me out.

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: The easiest way, would be to buy permalinks manager pro - Then you can use variables to completly build all structure the way you want it, bulk update and automatically redirect from the old urls to the new. Used it for years and have always been happy with it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am not a big fan of paying $350 for a problem that I am sure can be solved and I am nearly there to its solution. Moreover, I would love to understand how it can be fixed.